# Fourier Coefficients Absolutely Summable?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

When are the Fourier coefficients of $2\pi$-periodic functions summable? More specifically, which ones of $f(x) = (\cos x)^{100}$, $g(x) = \sin(\tan x)$, and 
$$
h(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+\pi, & : x\in[-\pi,0] \\
\pi-x, & : x\in (0,\pi]
\end{cases}
$$

are absolutely summable?

Comment: This is called the Wiener algebra (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_algebra). A small amount of regularity is necessary, e.g. Holder continuous for index strictly greater than 1/2.

Comment: You can't do better than that, but $(cos(x))^{100} $ is a trig polynomial, and it is easy to show that if the derivative is $\mathbb L^2$ then the original is absolutely summable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for summability, use Dini's theorem, or at least [the one I learned in my real analysis course](http://www.jlazovskis.com/docscurr/pm450.pdf#page=37) (I don't like Wikipedia's convoluted explanation of it). If the function is $L_1$, roughly meaning that it has a finite integral on the interval, and is Lipschitz continuous on the interval, then the partial sums converge to the function value, which hopefully is finite.

So then $f$ and $h$ have convergence everywhere (due to Lipschitz), but $g$ has continuity problems at $\pm\pi/2$, so Dini can't be applied there. At a glance, I'm quite sure convergence fails for $g$ at those spots.